# RubyMine debugging error

Tags: ruby, debugging, rubymine

I am try to run this method in RubyMine:

```
def test(a = "Ruby", b = "Rails")
  puts "The default value of a is #{a}."
  puts "The default value of b is #{b}."
end 
test("Hello", "World")
```

However, I keep getting this error:

```
16:06:41 Error running rubyProgamming: Cannot find RCov executable Ruby script for ruby-2.0.0-p481 (/usr/bin/ruby) SDK.
```

Any clues to what this means or how I can fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

RubyMine can't find the RCov executable. RubyMine allows you to specify what version of Ruby you want to use with your individual program. You need to install RCov into the SDK you are targeting.

Go to the menu bar and click on RubyMine -> Preferences... this will open the preferences window. In the list on the left hand side of the window click on "Languages and Frameworks", then the right you should see the version of the SDK you are using highlighted. In the far right side you will see a list of installed gems. At the bottom of that frame is a `+` plus sign. Click on that and it will open the window that shows all of the gems in your chosen repository. **This will take a little while to load if this is the first time you've opened this window in a while** it has to load the entire list of remote gems in the repository. Scroll down and find `rcov` and highlight it. Click the install button in the bottom right corner and install it. Click OK to back out of your preferences window and RubyMine should have `rcov` installed.

If you don't care about code coverage you can just go to the "Tools" menu and choose "Show Code Coverage Data". It will pop up the Code Coverage window and you can click on the "No Code Coverage" button to turn it off for that project. Then RubyMine shouldn't care that `rcov` isn't installed.

Comment: You can certainly just do `gem install 'rcov'` from the command line to install it. Or RubyMine might have popped up a window asking to install missing gems (that is now hidden at the bottom edge of the RubyMine window) and you can answer yes to that. But knowing how the preferences pane manages your Ruby environment is something you need to learn if you are going to use RubyMine.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that `rcov` is no longer being maintained and so if this persists you could do as I did and `gem install simplecov`.